# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'FieldDoesNotExist'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, field

I am having issues with my django admin area while adding data and selecting the

[image]

author which comes from relation from another class it gives the error written in title
the relation is

[image]

anyone with the answer will be helpfull thanks

Comment: Can you show a stacktrace & some code related to the error? Where does `FieldDoesNotExist` come into a couple of FKs?

Comment: Thaks Kyle Wang the problem solved

Comment: @kabirlodinwhat was the issue?